# What does it mean {{ trans(core.text) }} in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

I am new in Laravel and I am working on inbuilt project I have got `{{ trans(core.text) }}` after browse on internet I find that `trans` is a helper but I am not getting any file. So, Any one explain what does the line meaning `{{ trans(core.text) }}`.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `trans` function translates the given translation key using your localization files:

`echo trans('messages.welcome');`

If the specified translation key does not exist, the trans function will return the given key.

Link : https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers

Comment: Ok and If I specify `core` inside the `trans` helper function then how to know where is `core` @amer

Comment: In your language files: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/localization

`resources/lang ` directory